# ArrayAdapter for Webview inside Gridview

Tags: android, layout, webview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

Following on from an earlier question I'm trying to get multiple (widgets or in this case `WebView`s) inside a `GridView`.

So I wasn't really sure how to go about it whether to make my own adapter (seemed scary at the time) or create an `ArrayAdapter<WebView>`.

I wasn't really sure if `ArrayAdapter` could accept it like this or if it only supported primitive types.

```
GridView contentGrid;
LinearLayout contentLayout;

WebWidget[] webWidgets;

WebWidget web1;
WebWidget web2;
WebWidget web3;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    web1 = new WebWidget(this, "http://www.google.ie");
    web2 = new WebWidget(this, "http://www.facebook.com");
    web3 = new WebWidget(this, "http://www.youtube.ie");

    webWidgets = new WebWidget[]{web1,web2,web3};

    contentGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.contentGrid);

           //Heres my attempt at an adapter for webview
    ArrayAdapter<WebView> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<WebView>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, webWidgets);

    contentGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Unfortunately what comes out is the string version of the `WebView`.

So question is can I do it this way or am I better of making my own CustomAdapter?

NOTE: Could someone maybe point some information as to what the second constructor variable is? I.E  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you implement your `Adapter`, you cannot reliably put scrollable widgets in other scrollable widgets, at least where they scroll in the same direction. Since both `WebView` and `GridView` scroll vertically, you will get unreliable results trying to combine them this way.

With that, on to some of your statements and questions:

> I wasn't really sure if ArrayAdapter could accept it like this or if it only supported primitive types.

An `ArrayAdapter` can adapt a Java array or an `ArrayList` of whatever data type you like.

> Unfortunately what comes out is the string version of the webview...NOTE: Could someone maybe point some information as to what the second constructor variable is? I.E android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

The second constructor variable is what you want the cells in your `GridView` to look like. In your case, you are specifying a built-in layout resource that is a `TextView`. Hence, you are telling Android you want all your grid cells to be `TextView` widgets. Android will call `toString()` on the objects in your array, pour that result into the `TextView`, and the `TextViews` will go in your grid cells.

If you want your `ArrayAdapter` to be returning things other than a `TextView`, you will need to override `getView()` and handle more of that yourself, possibly using a layout file of your own creation.

> So question is can I do it this way or am i better of making my own CustomAdapter?

As noted at the outset of my answer, what you want simply will not work reliably.

Pretending for the moment that having `WebViews` in a `GridView` would work, the simplest solution would be for you to override `getView()` in your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter`, as I mentioned previously. Here is a [free excerpt from one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) that goes over this process.

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot of sense. About the webviews inside a grid, I know it seems kind of odd. But basically the webviews are going to contain individual javascript widgets. each one slightly different and there not going to be scrollable. Think of it like a speedial style app with different widgets on a 3x3 grid.